# Sort the table according to textbox (Numeric) values which is entered by user before submitting

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, textbox, tablesorter

Below is the image for your reference... This table with textbox is created with loop.. I have other columns too which is having values that fetched from db, I can able sort all of them.. But my problem is, I want to sort the first column in image according to the Numeric entries on the text box by user. It should sort it while I am clicking on its header..
I had searched google but couldn't solve.. If anyone of you can.. then that will be very useful.. I am using PHP, MySql, JQuery.

Thanks in advance..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you could do a relaod every time a header is clicked, send a get or post parameter with e.g. percentage+desc and then adjust the mysql query and the output in php.

Or you could go the easy way and do the ordering in javascript. Since you are using jQuery I can highly recommend the plugin Tablesorter: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: I think that is not what the OP meant. I think it's just about the 'visual' UI elements reordering...

Comment: thanks for your reply Horen.. but actually I want to sort the table according to the value which will be entered by user on TBoxes. I am able to sort rest of the columns because their values are fetched the while the page gets load, but not this coz, this will be entered by user.. I hope u got my problem.

Comment: I think you should be able to do this with tablesorter.js anyways. Can you explain a little more when you want to order the column? Should it be reorderd as soon as the user inputs a value?

Comment: Let User enter values first, then before submitting the form if user wants to check which one is the lowest value, then he can click on its headers to get it arranged according to input values...